# how to get image url on click in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to get image url on clicking the image from database in repeater
my database contains(id,url)

my repeater code is:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater" >
    <ItemTemplate >
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("url") %>' OnCommand="Image_Click" CommandName="ImageClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("url") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

my .cs code is

```
 protected void Image_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ImageClick")
        {
            string a=e.CommandArgument.tostring();
            responce.write(a);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do in ImageClick

```
((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl
```

to get the url of the clicked button

Answer (score 1):

Cast sender to ImageButton and read its ImageUrl property.

Also, is there a reason you are using command instead of handling ImageButtons click event?

Comment: i just want to get image url on clicking the image in repeater any how you can show me your way also

Comment: As Guigui said... ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl

Answer (score 1):

Both Vladimir and Guigui answers are prefer way of accessing URL of an image button.

If you also want ID value in addition to URL, you can store multiple values into  CommandArgument separated by comma.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%#Eval("url") %>' 
    OnCommand="Image_Command" 
    CommandName="ImageClick" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%> + "," + Eval("url") %>' />

protected void Image_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "ImageClick")
  {
    string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
       .Split(',');
    string id = commandArgs[0];
    string url = commandArgs[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: As url can be obtained from ImageUrl property, wouldn't it be more appropriate to just add Id to CommandArgument?

Comment: @VladimirKocjancic I agree with you. My answer is just for values in general such as ID, Name and so on. ***My bad; combination of ID and URL is not a good example.***